# Curl upload multiple php://memory files?

Tags: php, http, memory, curl, upload

I've created multiple memory based files like this:

```
$fp1 = fopen("php://memory", 'rw+');
fputs($fp1, "hello1");
rewind($fp1);

$fp2 = fopen("php://memory", 'rw+');
fputs($fp2, "hello2");
rewind($fp2);

echo stream_get_contents($fp1);
echo stream_get_contents($fp2);
```

Now I want these files to be uploadable by CURL. I know how to POST multiple files that exists on the disk with `$post['file'] = "@large.jpg";` but now my files are in memory.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there is no way for cURL to access the php:// files. I had a kind of similar problem and i created a memory disk on OS level

Unix:

```
mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
mkdir -p /ramcache
mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
```

This way you can still quite easily use a similar construction for php://memory

```
$fp1 = fopen('/ramcache/somefile1', 'rw+');
$fp2 = fopen('/ramcache/somefile2', 'rw+');
```

but also pass it as a real file to cURL, without having convert it from php://memory to a real file before passing it to cURL